# How can I prove that $ (3/p) = -1$ if $ p \equiv \pm 5 \pmod {12}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, legendre-symbol, congruence-relations

I know how to prove that $ (3/p) = 1$ if $ p \equiv \pm 1 \pmod {12}$ but I need to prove that $ (3/p) = -1$ if $ p \equiv \pm 5 \pmod {12}$, which the book write it as it is without explaining why after explaining the first case thoroughly. Could anyone explain for me why this is true please?

Comment: So for example, if $p = 11$ or $p=13$, why is $3/p=1$ when $3/11 \ne 1 \ne 3/13$?

Comment: It's called the Legendre symbol. In this case, the notation $/$ doesn't denote fraction. It denotes a number associated with the property of whether or not a number is a square modulo $p$. The textbook you have should have an explanation of how the symbol is defined and how to calculate it.

Comment: @gt6989b Those aren't fractions https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol The parentheses give it away, as does the tag. At least when you've heard about them before.

Comment: Sounds like a case for [quadratic reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity)

Answer (score 2):

A possible way is as follows. Both rely on the following fact: Let $p>3$ be prime. $-3$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$ if and only if $p\equiv 1\pmod{6}$. Now, let me first give a self-contained proof of this fact. Let $x\equiv 2a+1\pmod{p}$ such that $x^2\equiv -3\pmod{p}$ (note that such an $a$ must indeed exist as $p\neq 2$). Now, $4a^2+4a+4\equiv 0\pmod{p}$, that is, $p\mid a^2+a+1$.  This implies, $a^3\equiv 1\pmod{p}$. Now, if $p\equiv 5\pmod{6}$, then letting $p=6\ell+5$, we have $a^{p-1}=a^{6\ell+4}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$. Moreover,  $a^3\equiv 1\pmod{p}$ also implies $a^{6\ell+3}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$, and thus, $a\equiv 1\pmod{p}$, which yields $a^2+a+1\equiv 3\pmod{p}$, which is clear contradiction. Thus. $p\not\equiv 5\pmod{6}$, and since  $p>3$ we deduce   $p\equiv 1\pmod{6}$. Now,

**Case 1** If $p\equiv 5\pmod{12}$, we also enjoy $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$, and thus, $(\frac{3}{p})=(\frac{-3}{p})=-1$ (where the second equality follows from the fact above) this clearly yields $3$ is not a quadratic residue modulo $p$.

**Case  2** Now, let $p\equiv 7\pmod{12}$. Then, $-3$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$, whereas $-1$ is not, and thus, $3$ is not a q. residue either.

**Edit:** (to address a comment by @rtybase below). I believe this argument should also extend to composite $p$. If $p=p_1^{\beta_1}\cdots p_k^{\beta_k}$, then $-3$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$ if and only if $-3$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p_i$ for every $i $ (if $-3$ is a q. residue modulo $p$, then it must also be so for any $p_i$. conversely, we can establish by Chinese remainder theorem that, if $x^2\equiv -3\pmod{p_i}$ holds, then we can  pass to  $p$. From $p_i\to p_i^{\beta_i}$ is also not hard, and is well-known.

Answer (score 1):

You need the "Law of Quadratic Reciprocity". Please check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity.

Comment: We usually prefer answers on this site to be self-contained. Links are a terrific supplement, but they shouldn't me the main component of an answer post. For instance, if Wikipedia decides to rename that article, and fails to provide a redirect, this answer loses most of its value.

Comment: Indeed. It also fits as a comment ... oh, but there is a similar comment already, posted 3 minutes earlier.

Comment: Also, OP's didn't mention $p$ should be prime. It would be nice to clarify this first.

Answer (score 1):

First we note that (by the law of quadratic reciprocity):
$$\left(\frac{3}{p}\right)=\bigg(\frac{p}{3}\bigg)(-1)^{\tfrac{p-1}{2}\cdot\tfrac{3-1}{2}}=\bigg(\frac{p}{3}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{-1}{p}\bigg)$$
Now, if $p\equiv 5 \pmod{12}$ then
$$\bigg(\frac{p}{3}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{-1}{p}\bigg)=\bigg(\frac{5}{3}\bigg)\cdot1=\bigg(\frac{2}{3}\bigg)=(-1)^{\tfrac{3^2-1}{8}}=-1$$
And, if $p\equiv -5 \pmod{12}$ then...

Comment: OP's didn't mention $p$ should be prime. It would be nice to clarify this first.

Comment: If not, it would be pointless to talk about the Legendre symbol.

Comment: That was mentioned in the comments ... by other people, not OP.

Comment: @rtybase the original post had the tag of legendre symbol. The wiki link in the comments says 'for an odd prime number p'. So even though op didn't explicitly say it was prime, their tags say it has to be prime

Comment: But why we checked only $5 & -5$ for p to be congruent to, where are the rest of the numbers mod 12 other than 1 and 11?

Comment: In the fifth line how is (-1/p) = 1? May be because if $ p \equiv 5 \pmod {12}$ then p is always an odd prime then p-1 is an even 1 but then also the power finally may be even or odd.

Comment: $p\equiv 5 \pmod{12}$ implies $p\equiv 5\equiv 1 \pmod{4}$, hence $\left(\frac{-1}{p}\right)=1$.